# Regex for validating multiple Inputs as per the below regex

Tags: regex

I have a regex that validates my inputs like

**Regex :** 
`^(?=.{1,15}$)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:[-]{1})[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`

**Example 1:** `BBB-123BBB`

Now, I want to create a regex using the above, where my regex can validate multiple inputs with a semicolon (`;`) as a delimiter & the maximum input that can be there is 20.

**Like for ex 2:**
`BBB-123BB,AAA-1234;EEE-9876....20 items`

**Ex 2.**
`BB-123BB,AAA3-1234;EEE334-9876....20 items`

How can I extend my regex above (the first one) to allow multiple inputs to be added while letting them be split by a semicolon and can have a maximum of 20 items (as shown in ex 2)?

Comment: Did you mean for the comma in the example to be a semicolon, too?

Comment: The simplest way is to split on `;` and check each substring with the same regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on your pattern, I removed unnecessary capturing groups and used simple `-`, which is equivalent to `(?:[-]{1})`. Here's what I came up with:

```
^(?:(?:^|;)(?=[^;]{1,15})[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+){1,20}$
```

Explanation:

`^` - match beginning of a string

`(?:...)` - non-capturing group

`^|;` - alternation: match `;` literally or match beginning of string

`[^;]{1,15};` - match between 1 and 15 characters other than `;`

`{1,20}` - match preceding pattern between 1 and 20 times

`$` - match end of a string

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rByf3a/2)

EDIT: Pattern:

```
^(?=[^;]{1,15})[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:;(?=[^;]{1,15})[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+){0,19}$
```

won't accept `;` at the beginning.

SECOND EDIT:

```
^(?=[^;]{1,15}(?:;|$))[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:;(?=[^;]{1,15})[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+){0,19}$
```

Added: `(?:;|$)` - match either `;` literally or `$` - end of string

What it does: correctly limits length of a token to 15

Comment: But this regex doesn't suffice the check for each value length should of max 15 char only.

Comment: If I give this input `A-1234111111111111111111111111111`, it is accepting it. where as it should not, since the length of the input is more than 15 chars.

Comment: The updated regex is working fine only for single input, when I am giving multiple inputs, then it's not working like below :
`AA-A12123434545; AAO-PLPLPLPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP; AAF-OP987`
The second input is not a valid one, but the regex is accepting it.

Comment: I guess I finally got it, the below regex will suffice my inputs.
`^(?=[^;]{1,15}(?:;|$))[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:;(?=[^;]{1,15}(?:;|$))[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+){0,19}$`





***Now, if I want to have 2 delimeters like (;) & (,), how can i achieve that in this regex ??***

Comment: @Sheegy `[^;]` should be `[^;,]` now and `(?:;|$))` should be `(?:;|$|,))`

Answer (score 1):

If the maximum is not important to enforce, simply allow arbitrary repetitions.

```
^(?=[^;]{3,15}(?:;[^;]{3,15})*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+(;[a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

If you want to specifically allow between 0 and 19 repeats, change the last `*` to `{0,19}`.

The minimal string which can match the main expression has three characters; so I updated the length constraint to `{3,15}`.

A minus simply matches itself so there is no need to put it in a character class; and there is never a good reason to specify a single repetition of anything, so I simplified the main regex accordingly.